# .net Blazor Desktop folder picker?

Tags: wpf, explorer, webview2, maui-blazor, blazor-desktop

I am using a WPF Desktop app with BlazorWebView. I would like to open up file explorer and have the user select a folder to get the path selected. I can use the browser input to select files but as I understand it is a limitation of the browser to allow me to select a folder path. Is there a Folder Picker for native access?

The Process.Start only seem to open the file explorer and won't let me choose the folder.

```xml
<blazor:BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot\index.html" Services="{DynamicResource services}">
            <blazor:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <blazor:RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type shared:App}" />
            </blazor:BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </blazor:BlazorWebView>
```

```html
@using System.Diagnostics


<button @onclick="OnClickOpenNativeFileExplorer">Open</button>

@code {
    private void OnClickOpenNativeFileExplorer(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("explorer.exe");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `FolderBrowserDialog`?

Comment: @mm8 if I use the FolderBrowserDialog I am unsure how to call it from a razor component. Any ideas?

Comment: @mm8 oh wait... I think I got it. I can use dependency Injection!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I was able to solve it by doing the following.

I added the IFolderPicker interface to my razor class library. Then implement the FolderPicker in the WPF project using a NuGet package.

```
Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-Shell -Version 1.1.1
```

```
public interface IFolderPicker
{
    public string DisplayFolderPicker();
}

public class FolderPicker : IFolderPicker
{
        public string DisplayFolderPicker()
        {
            var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
            dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
            CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
                return dialog.FileName;
            return "";
        }
}
```

I then register the dependency using the DI container within the MainWindow.xaml.cs file.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddWpfBlazorWebView();

            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IFolderPicker, FolderPicker>();

            Resources.Add("services", serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
        }
```

Then within the razor component, I have a button that calls the DisplayFolderPicker method.

```
@inject IFolderPicker _folderPicker


<button @onclick="OnClickOpenNativeFileExplorer">Open</button>
<p>@path</p>

@code {
    private string path = "";
    private void OnClickOpenNativeFileExplorer(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        path = _folderPicker.DisplayFolderPicker();

    }
}
```

Take-away: I suppose not only will this work for FolderPicker but for calling any native component.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! For my Windows application project using BlazorWebView, I setup the DI in Form1.cs using services.AddTransient<IFolderPicker, FolderPicker>(); where services is a ServiceCollection. Then add it to the webview using blazorWebView1.Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();